# How to close react-native modal on pressing escape key? (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, modal-dialog, keyboard-events

Is it possible to close react-native 'Modal' on pressing the escape key? I know other libraries 'react-modal' where Modal closes on pressing escape key out of box. But seems react-native Modal doesn't have this functionality out of box.

```
import { Modal } from "react-native";
<Modal
      visible={isOpen}
      transparent={true}
      animationType={"fade"}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        console.log("On request close");
        this.closeModal();
      }}
    >
      <View>
        // Other UI elements here
      </View>
</Modal>
```

"onRequestClose" is not called when Escape key is pressed. Any workaround on how to close modal on pressing escape key?

Note: There is no TextInput which I have seen being suggested in few answers to capture key press events, so that cannot be used.